# Type Provider issue - main EntryPoint - Syntax

Tags: .net, f#, type-providers, f#-3.0

I was able to get a piece of code to run in an .fsx script. I never did see it loop over the track data I'm pulling back. So I thought I would put it in an .fs file and compile it. I'm running into 2 issues. F# IDE underlines the type keyword and the let in the let query = line. Here is my oode (below) Where am I off on the syntax?

```
open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=SQLDEV;Initial Catalog=CDDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;">
            let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
            // Enable the logging of database activity to the console.
            db.DataContext.Log <- System.Console.Out
            let query1 =
                query {
                    for row in db.SoundRecording do
                    select row
                    take 50
                }
            query1 |> Seq.iter (fun row -> printfn "%s - %s" row.DisplayArtist row.DisplayTitle)
            0 // return an integer exit code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work - you can't have type definitions inside functions

```
open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=SQLDEV;Initial Catalog=CDDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;">
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

            let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
            // Enable the logging of database activity to the console.
            db.DataContext.Log <- System.Console.Out
            let query1 =
                query {
                    for row in db.SoundRecording do
                    select row
                    take 50
                }
            query1 |> Seq.iter (fun row -> printfn "%s - %s" row.DisplayArtist row.DisplayTitle)
            0 // return an integer exit code
```